# Wiring for AC unit

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, electrical-panel, air-conditioning

I am planning on having central AC installed, and am planning on pulling a permit and performing the electrical work myself to save on costs. I’m comfortable with the electrical side of things(former Navy Electrician and oil refinery electrician) but never had to deal with residential code. I’m working my way through the NEC, and can’t find the requirements for how to seal/ weather proof the conductors once they exit the house. Also if conduit needs to be run from the panel all the way to the disconnect. My panel is in the garage, set into the drywall, so will be running the conductors behind drywall through a hole outside. From that point not sure what fittings are required. If anyone can point me to the correct section, would appreciate.

Comment: Can you run the wiring indoors until it turns out into the back of the AC disconnect, or do you need to have part of the run inside and part of the run outside?

Comment: I can do that as an option, but would mean cutting holes in the drywall and drilling through the vertical beams. I haven’t consulted with a AC installer yet on where the unit would/ should go… good suggestion, didn’t think about your route, especially if the exchanger is further down the wall.

Comment: Don't bother with the NEC proper.  It is not for learning, and it says so right in Article 90.1(A). *"This Code is not intended as a design specification or an instruction manual"*. Even if they're a bit beneath you, just grab books on home wiring.  It's straightforward stuff.  Also here's a tip: No DIY electrician ever got written up for using conduit.  If you lay competent conduit the entire route, even if you bung something up like use #12 when you needed #10, it's super easy to fix it. Also conduit lets you put up to 4 circuits per pipe, and use THHN/THWN wires, which are higher ampacity.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go so I will say how I usually do it.

Whole house compressor 240v and service receptacle 120v

Note the service receptacle can be tapped from another branch circuit  on the same wall or if there is a receptacle within 50’ that one will be ok if you can see it from the outside unit.

Inside the walls that are going to be covered I will use smurf tube (normally blue in color flexible non metallic conduit) way easier and cheaper than rigid.

Pull thhn/thwn wires through the smurf tube to an outside disconnect. If you do not have a service receptacle within 50’
a disconnect that also has the receptacle can be handy the 3 conductors for the receptacle can run in the same tube.

The disconnect can be fused or not.

Normally a piece metallic liquid tight or non metallic liquid tight flex from the disconnect to the outside unit a box end or threaded connector on each end of the flex
As far as sealing we normally use silicone or even expanding foam

Code is light on the sealing I usually put a bead of silicone around the hole and a single bead along the top of the disconnect.

If using individual conductors like thhn conduit is required.
If you wanted to use nmb no conduit is needed , nmb can only go to the disconnect.

You could use UF wire in the walls and exit but if is a bugger to put in flex and it will usually require a protective conduit so I go with THHN (it has been dual rated for decades.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. From the panel down is free and clear with no insulation or obstructions, easiest route but would depend on where they can put the ac unit. Need to get someone out to see where it should go.

Comment: I would suggest sizing conduit for #8 and pulling #10 if that is adequate for your condensing unit.  I am assuming a 4 ton which will need about 20 amps.The larger wire will not add that much cost and the system will operate nicely with the over size wire.